# SQL query related to Joins and count

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Please clarify my sql query question.

I have 4 tables in my sql server example as below:

```
Products ---> Id, productname
Suppliers ---> Id, ProductId, suppliername
Customer --> Id, supplierId, customername, orderId
Orders --> Id, ordername
```

Input to my stored procedure is productId.

I want to fetch All suppliers whose productid is my sqlproc parameter (input) 
 and **Count** of OrderIds with ordername = 'orderorange'  --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductId, productname, suppliername,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE Id = 1 and Customer.supplierId = Suppliers.Id) AS CountCustomer1
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE ordername = 'orderorange') AS CountOrderOrange
FROM Suppliers
WHERE ProductId = ?
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your query, I'm getting output with two rows and countCustomer1 as 1 in both rows. But we need to get 1st row countCustomer1 as 1 and second row countCustomer1 as 0 as in my picture, there is no customer1 associated for supplier2. Please check ?

Comment: Are we missing group by with supplierID for count?

Comment: @surya oh sorry! I think I got it. Try `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE Id = 1 and Customer.supplierId = Suppliers.Id) AS CountCustomer1`. You are telling the nested query to select only the rows with the supplierId equals to the one of the parent query. If it works I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes Luca. It works well. Thank you for your quick help.